# Mysql - Parse error (syntax error) in my code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I use:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
```

in my class, As a result display Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mysqli' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in D:\xamppp\htdocs\cms\includes\td-class-db.php on line 12
```

And when use `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');` outsilde the class no display any error!

My class:

```
class Connect_db{
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
}
```

why?

Comment: Put that in  `__construct()`. Probably `$this->mysqli = etc...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't instantiate classes when creating member variables in a class. You have to do this in the constructor or a method:

```
class Connect_db{
    private $mysqli;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx John Conde

how to use static function for this function?

Comment: Why does this need to be static?

Comment: all my functions is static and easy to use.wrong?

Comment: Methods only need to be static under certain circumstances. It isn't very common. This isn't one of those circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a class method like constructor.

```
class Connect_db
{

  function __construct()
  {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
  }
}
```